# How to send camera stream to rtmp server by react native

Tags: react-native, video-streaming, streaming, rtmp, react-native-camera

I am trying to build a live stream video app.
I built an **rtmp server** which is ready for publishing and playing streams. I need a way to capture mobile's user camera and send the online stream to my rtmp server.

I use react-native in client side. I found [react-native-camera](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera) which is great in dealing with camera but I couldn't find any **event/api** available for accessing camera stream in their documentations.

Another problem is the way that I have to send the stream to rtmp server. I have no knowledge in this area so any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: There's no way, or react-native package support you to access camera frame while open camera. Maybe this is the solution https://medium.com/react-native-development/tutorial-react-native-camera-app-with-live-preview-saturation-and-brightness-filters-2147499ddbec. But I think this solution not good for doing a live stream app.

Comment: thanks @Burdy. Please suggest the best practices if you know a better solution.

Comment: I found this repo: https://github.com/NodeMedia/react-native-nodemediaclient. and I think this should be the solution. I have no luck in my first attempt. still digging...

Comment: I think it's good. Good luck buddy.

Answer (score 11):

For anyone else who faces the same issue, This repo is the ultimate solution.

https://github.com/NodeMedia/react-native-nodemediaclient

Comment: this package is not opening the camera. Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: I had no issue with that.

Comment: I have the same issue with this library. Unable to open camera in android device. I'm using ignite boilerplate for architecture. When I'm running without ignite boilerplate it works properly in both android and ios.

Comment: For people who are unable to open camera, have you added camera permissions in your manifest file?

Comment: @EhsanMajdabadi I can change the video size but quality is poor, and i can't achieve HD quality while video is in HD size!

Comment: Hi @EhsanMajdabadi ! Did you manage to get it running ? It would be nice to know if you were using expo or any other setup ? I am facing quite a few issues in starting it up. Thanks !

Comment: @UtsavT I got it done in both a pure react-native project and expo project last year. Many things ve happened since last year and I am not sure it's still working.

Comment: @EhsanMajdabadi That's very true - because I have been having a hard time fixing it. If you can share a working example (package.json, package.lock included) it would be very very helpful ! :)

Comment: I am also having a hard time getting it to show the camera in my ios device. I was able to get the RNCamera package to easily request permission and display the camera, but that doesn't seem to have an api to push to an rtmp server, which I also need. The react-native-nodemediaclient documentation is poor and out of date, does anybody have troubleshooting tips?

Comment: I'm having problem with audio using this lib. I'm able to publish video live but no audio...

Comment: https://github.com/NodeMedia/react-native-nodemediaclient is now archived. Any active repo that serves the same purpose and feature guys?

Comment: Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RCTNodeCamera" was not found in the UIManager.

Facing this issue in Expo React Native App

Also, the repo has been archived.

Is there any other solution?

Comment: @AlvinTheodora have you come up with something? Needing one

Answer (score 1):

// For 2023, the situation has changed a lot and the need for RTMP is questionable

Namely, from mobile devices, even through React-Native, you can make full-fledged broadcasts via WebRTC
It works both through modules like **react-native-webrtc** and through the web in **WebView**

With the module, the device warms up less, there are fewer time delays, but it is not possible to squeeze the maximum out of the camera. In addition, it is impossible to normally take pictures in high resolution during the broadcast. In addition to this, the implementation itself is limited in comparison with the web (but how much is unclear because there is not even normal documentation except for a few simple usage examples)
As if this is not enough, the main logic of the work is implemented in C++ and NDK, the module contains already compiled blocks with wrappers in Java and JS, which greatly complicates any improvements

On the web with WebView - almost all the functionality of WebRTC is supported, i.e. you can just read the documentation and do according to it.

Another huge plus of this is that a server is not always required for broadcasting (you can broadcast video-audio from one phone to another, and so on)

But it was not without nuances:

1. You can't just start broadcasting from http, you need https, without which a browser API that provides the ability to receive audio-video streams simply will not be provided.
2. Accordingly, a certificate is needed for https. Whether it will be someone's or self-signed is another question. BUT WebView on the same Android, without additional improvements, refuses to accept self-signed certificates, even installed in the system, even with pocket certification agencies installed.
3. The certificate requires a host or a permanent IP address
4. (!!!) Directly and without major problems, the devices broadcast to each other only while on the same network! When you are in different networks behind NATs, you will need an intermediate server through which media streams will go
5. Within the same network, the devices exchange broadcasts perfectly, provided that none of the devices is an access point (i.e. if WiFi is distributed from the phone "1" and a couple more phones connect to it - "2" and "3", then "2" and "3" will be able to exchange, but "1" - will not be able to broadcast for others, nor receive broadcasts from them, provided there is no access to the Internet and external servers). Perhaps there is some solution, but a phone without root imposes very tangible restrictions - you can't even register your host

There is also an excellent module for working with the camera **react-native-vision-camera**, which provides a huge number of opportunities to work with the camera, but it cannot broadcast.
But it provides the ability to apply filters to the video stream (without transferring to JS. On the native side, a buffer containing each frame is created and passed to the filter - about 10 MB. Due to this, very high performance is achieved. With some modifications, nothing prevents you from implementing a filter/plugin that would broadcast frames with a video stream. Unfortunately, this is not applicable to the sound yet)

Comment: [Posts on Stack Overflow have to be in English](/help/non-english-questions). Do not post bilingual posts. If you feel more comfortable writing in Russian, try our sister site [ru.so].

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the [NodeMediaClient](https://github.com/naveensaini4u/NodeMediaClient/tree/master) library for this task. I've used it successfully in a similar scenario. Here's a step-by-step guide to get you started:

Set up an RTMP server on Nginx: Follow this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n-EdUHNK9UI) to set up your RTMP server. This will be the endpoint where your stream will be sent.

Test with OBS Studio and VLC: Before integrating with React Native, it's essential to ensure that your server setup works correctly. Test your RTMP server using OBS Studio for broadcasting and VLC for viewing. Confirm that the stream is being transmitted and received as expected.

Integrate with React Native: Once your server is confirmed to be working, integrate the streaming functionality into your React Native application.

Below is a sample code snippet to help you get started:

```
<pre><code>
import React, {useRef, useState} from 'react';
import {Button, Dimensions, PermissionsAndroid, View} from 'react-native';
import {NodeCameraView} from 'react-native-nodemediaclient';
const App = () => {
  const [isPublish, setIsPublish] = useState(false);
  const [publishBtnTitle, setPublishBtnTitle] = useState('Start Publish');
  const vpRef = useRef();

  const {width, height} = Dimensions.get('window');

  const config = {
    cameraConfig: {
      cameraId: 1,
      cameraFrontMirror: false,
    },
    videoConfig: {
      preset: 4,
      bitrate: 2000000,
      profile: 2,
      fps: 30,
      videoFrontMirror: true,
    },
    audioConfig: {
      bitrate: 128000,
      profile: 1,
      samplerate: 44100,
    },
  };

  const handleStatus = event => {
    console.log('RTMP Status:', event);
  };

  const startStream = async () => {
    await PermissionsAndroid.request(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA);
    try {
      vpRef.current.start();
      setPublishBtnTitle('Stop Publish');
      setIsPublish(true);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error starting stream:', error);
    }
  };

  const stopStream = () => {
    vpRef.current.stop();
    setPublishBtnTitle('Start Publish');
    setIsPublish(false);
  };

  const streamKey = 'your-stream-key';
  const url = `rtmp://your-server-ip-address:1935/live/${streamKey}`;

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <NodeCameraView
        style={{height: 300}}
        ref={vpRef}
        outputUrl={url}
        camera={config.cameraConfig}
        audio={config.audioConfig}
        video={config.videoConfig}
        autopreview={true}
        onStatus={event => handleStatus(event)}
      />
      <Button title={publishBtnTitle} onPress={isPublish ? stopStream : startStream} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
</code></pre>
```

Replace 'your-stream-key' with your actual stream key, and 'your-server-ip-address' with the IP address of your RTMP server. This should get you up and running with streaming in React Native using NodeMediaClient.

Remember to handle permissions properly, especially for camera access on Android devices.

Feel free to contact me if you have any  questions!